# Angular 5 Class extends class with injections

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, angular5, extends

I created such a class

```
@Injectable FooService {

    constructor(private _bar:BarService){

    }
}
```

And extended it like this

```
@Injectable ExtFooService extends FooService {

    constructor(private _bar:BarService){
        super(_bar);
    }
}
```

In this way I get the following error:

> Error:(12, 14) TS2415:Class 'ExtFooService' incorrectly extends base class 'FooService'. Types have separate declarations of a private property '_bar'.

Why is that so?

I tried removing the injections from the ExtFooService, but I get this at the `super()` line:

> Error:(21, 9) TS2554:Expected 2 arguments, but got 0.

Is it really necessary that I do this?

```
@Injectable ExtFooService extends FooService {

    constructor(private _extBar:BarService){
        super(_extBar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should remove the `private` from the argument `_bar` in the derived class. The `private` is short hand for declaring a field with the same name as the constructor argument and initializing it with the value of the argument. Since the base class already declared the field, there is no need to redeclare it in the derived class:

```
@Injectable ExtFooService extends FooService {

    constructor(_bar:BarService){
        super(_bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: And this doesn't make _bar public?

Comment: @TonySamperi If you want the argument to be a public field you would have to explicitly add `public`. If you don't specify any modifier it is just a constructor argument not a class memeber

Comment: Cool. Thank you

Comment: Wow thanks, I've been searching for about an hour just to find that `private` was blocking the whole thing. In my case though, it was in the class that extends the base class, where the key word `private` needed to be removed.